# Having issue in installing Specflow plus Excel in Visual studio 2017 with SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-3-0 Installed

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I tried Installing the SpecRun+Excel but after Installing I am facing the following Issue post Rebiuld **`Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\XYZ\source\repos\XYZ_LATEST_PROJECT\packages\SpecFlow.2.3.2\tools\specflow.exe' or one of its dependencies.`**

Comment: Is the file there?

Comment: @Andreas Willich After Installation my SpecRun.exe got Disappeared

Comment: What now? SpecFlow.exe or SpecRun.exe? That's two different files.
I would suggest you open an issue for it: https://specflow.org/specflow-support/